# Increasing blue color of all objects in a THREE.JS Scene

Tags: three.js, qubit

What is the best way to increase the blue color of all of the objects in a scene?

In my THREE.JS Scene there is a blue object that randomly pops up... I would like it to be more noticeable...

I have tried altering the colors with a frameBuffer...

I have also tried some post-processing filters...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this issue is to use a color correction post processing pass. Depending on how you configure the uniforms of `ColorCorrectionShader`, you end up with different color values. One approach to increase the blue values is to configure the `mulRGB` uniform with a value of e.g. `(1, 1, 10)`.

Below is a complete live example:

```js
import * as THREE from 'three';

import { EffectComposer } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js';
import { RenderPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/RenderPass.js';
import { ShaderPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js';
import { OutputPass } from 'three/addons/postprocessing/OutputPass.js';
import { ColorCorrectionShader } from 'three/addons/shaders/ColorCorrectionShader.js';

let container;

let camera, scene, renderer, composer;

let mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

  //

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 27, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3500 );
  camera.position.z = 2750;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x050505 );
  scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x050505, 2000, 3500 );

  //

  scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc ) );

  const light1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
  light1.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
  scene.add( light1 );

  const light2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 4.5 );
  light2.position.set( 0, - 1, 0 );
  scene.add( light2 );

  //

  const triangles = 160000;

  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

  const positions = [];
  const normals = [];
  const colors = [];

  const color = new THREE.Color();

  const n = 800, n2 = n / 2;    // triangles spread in the cube
  const d = 12, d2 = d / 2; // individual triangle size

  const pA = new THREE.Vector3();
  const pB = new THREE.Vector3();
  const pC = new THREE.Vector3();

  const cb = new THREE.Vector3();
  const ab = new THREE.Vector3();

  for ( let i = 0; i < triangles; i ++ ) {

    // positions

    const x = Math.random() * n - n2;
    const y = Math.random() * n - n2;
    const z = Math.random() * n - n2;

    const ax = x + Math.random() * d - d2;
    const ay = y + Math.random() * d - d2;
    const az = z + Math.random() * d - d2;

    const bx = x + Math.random() * d - d2;
    const by = y + Math.random() * d - d2;
    const bz = z + Math.random() * d - d2;

    const cx = x + Math.random() * d - d2;
    const cy = y + Math.random() * d - d2;
    const cz = z + Math.random() * d - d2;

    positions.push( ax, ay, az );
    positions.push( bx, by, bz );
    positions.push( cx, cy, cz );

    // flat face normals

    pA.set( ax, ay, az );
    pB.set( bx, by, bz );
    pC.set( cx, cy, cz );

    cb.subVectors( pC, pB );
    ab.subVectors( pA, pB );
    cb.cross( ab );

    cb.normalize();

    const nx = cb.x;
    const ny = cb.y;
    const nz = cb.z;

    normals.push( nx, ny, nz );
    normals.push( nx, ny, nz );
    normals.push( nx, ny, nz );

    // colors

    const vx = ( x / n ) + 0.5;
    const vy = ( y / n ) + 0.5;
    const vz = ( z / n ) + 0.5;

    color.setRGB( vx, vy, vz );

    const alpha = Math.random();

    colors.push( color.r, color.g, color.b, alpha );
    colors.push( color.r, color.g, color.b, alpha );
    colors.push( color.r, color.g, color.b, alpha );

  }

  function disposeArray() {

    this.array = null;

  }

  geometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ).onUpload( disposeArray ) );
  geometry.setAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ).onUpload( disposeArray ) );
  geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 4 ).onUpload( disposeArray ) );

  geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    color: 0xd5d5d5, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 250,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide, vertexColors: true, transparent: true
  } );

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  scene.add( mesh );

  //

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  //

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
  
  //
  
  const renderPass = new RenderPass( scene, camera );
  const colorCorrectionPass = new ShaderPass( ColorCorrectionShader );
  const outputPass = new OutputPass();
  
  colorCorrectionPass.uniforms[ 'powRGB' ].value.set( 1, 1, 1 );
    colorCorrectionPass.uniforms[ 'mulRGB' ].value.set( 1, 1, 10 );

  composer = new EffectComposer( renderer );
  composer.addPass( renderPass );
  composer.addPass( colorCorrectionPass );
  composer.addPass( outputPass );

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  composer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

//

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  render();

}

function render() {

  const time = Date.now() * 0.001;

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.25;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 0.5;

  composer.render();

}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/cg5eyj3b/4/

Comment: Note that the OP posted exactly *zero code* - this is not something that should be answered. And you can look at their other two questions which are equally lacking (including the latest which is complete gibberish)